# Object Constraint Jump

Tags: constraints

I have been making a clock mechanism in blender and I am using object constraints. The problem is that it makes a jump once I reach 180 degrees. Notice in the video that there are 3 gears. The smallest one at the bottom is the one being rotated. The one on the right has a rotate constraint with a .50 influence relative to the smallest. The biggest one with half of it painted white(to show the issue) has a rotate constraint .20 influence relative to the one on the right. Link for video: https://youtu.be/GnI0c6Tu0Q0

Comment: Maybe by using the "Transformation Constraint" instead of the "Rotation Constraint" with the "Extrapolate" mode enebled as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=j1WNbpX7HPo at about 10 min in the tutorial.

Comment: I mean just for the big gear...